# Issues with sending email using sendgrid after account is registered on web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I created a asp.net core web app (mvc) project where I am integrating the nuget package `SendGrid`. For some reason whenever I am registering an account and hitting submit, it will tell me

[image]

So, when I go check my email it does not show up, not even junk folder. The `From = new EmailAddress()`, I used an email that does not exist and that did not work. So I then decided to use the email I used when I created the sendgrid account to obtain the api key and that did not work either, not even after creating a whole new email.

**Is there something I am doing that is causing the email not to get sent to the email I listed on the account registration?**

Inside of `Startup.cs`, I added the transient for sendgrid:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

My class `EmailSenderService.cs` handles the email sending:

```
public class EmailSenderService : IEmailSender
    {

        public EmailSenderService(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("info@example.com", "Identity Demo"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
```

`appsettings.json`

```
 {
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=aspnet-ASP.NET_Core_IdentityDemo-2BDAC3A8-E5A9-492C-891F-EE1996D434EE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "SendGridUser": "apikey",
      "SendGridKey": "MY API KEY",
      "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

I checked to see if the settings of the API was allowing to send emails and it is...

[image]

---

**UPDATED**

Ctor getting error for setting `Options` to a value.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a few changes that worked for me.

First I'd amend your Email Sender class as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("info@example.com", "Identity Demo"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
```

Create a new Class to your project called **AuthMessageSenderOptions**:

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
        public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
        public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

Update Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
        }
```

Finally, update your appSettings.json file:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=aspnet-ASP.NET_Core_IdentityDemo-2BDAC3A8-E5A9-492C-891F-EE1996D434EE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "SendGridUser": "apikey",
  "SendGridKey": "INSERT YOUR API KEY",
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: So you are saying have it as `"Username": apikey` instead of `"Username": "apikey"`? If so, I tried to do it but it did not like it and said `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Could not parse the JSON file.`

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  I've updated my answer to show how you appSettings.json file should look.

Comment: No worries, I went ahead and did that but I still do not get the email sent.... this is what I did to obtain the api key. I went to `https://api.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/csharp then clicked on create key which gave me the api key. Then I used that and placed it inside of my `appsettings.json`. Is there something I am missing in order to get this to work? Any other steps/configurations I must do on the app.sendgrid.com to get emails to be sent out?

Comment: With the API key that you set up.  What access level did you give it?  Full Access?

Also, when you step through the code.  Can you see the credentials being passed when you call the SendEmailAsync method?

Comment: I gave it full access when I created the API key. When I am stepping through the code, I am able to see the email address that I typed in the email textfield, subject will show "Confirm your email", HtmlContent will show Please confirm your account by `<a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");` then after its done stepping through it displays on the page "Register Confirmation please check your email to confirm your account". I check my email and I do not see anything.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after instantiating the client.  What values are set against _username and _apikey?

Comment: _username is set as "apikey" and _apikey is set as the API key that is from SendGrid

Comment: If you check the Activity page in SendGrid does it show your email activity in there?

Comment: When I go to Activity Feed the dates are preloaded, when I click on the calendar box it says You have 3 days of activity available. Need More? So I then hit search but it says no search found... and at the top of the word Activity Feed there's a green bar that says Before sending your first email, you'll need to create a sender identity.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a solution that has worked for me.

Comment: Much appreciated it! For the ctor `Options = optionsAccessor.Value;` is `Options` a readonly property in that `EmailSenderService.cs` file? Because when I set `Options` equal to something it says `Options` is a type but used as a variable... it doesn't like that.

Comment: I think this may be to do with the usings.  I've updated the answer to show the usings I have in the EmailSender class.

Comment: Hmm I added your usings and still am getting the same error.. please view my updated post so you can see the screenshot for the ctor

Comment: Can you post what your Startup.cs file looks like now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233893/discussion-between-kev-ritchie-and-novicecoder).